# How can I activate a button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am doing a dashboard, in my menu the problem is that I am not working as usual with a `class component`, if not with `react hooks`, I know little javascript so it is complicated for me

previously in class component I have performed this function:

```
class Technologies extends Component {
  handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="section-7">
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleChange(false)}
          className={`btnT _1 ${this.state.checked === false}`}
        >
          FACIAL RECOGNITION
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
          className={`btnT  ${this.state.checked === true}`}
        >
          OBJECT DETECTION
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I need to make the new code active

```
export default () => {
  const [pantalla, setView] = useState(<RealTime />)
  let cambiarpantalla = View => {
    setView(<View />)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="border-primary border-l-2 shadow-active "
        onClick={() => cambiarpantalla(RealTime)}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center  cursor-pointer mx-4  p-4 border-b border-line">
          <Real />
          <p className="ml-3">Real Time</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => cambiarpantalla(Analitycs)}>
        <div className="flex items-center  cursor-pointer  p-4 mx-4 border-b border-line">
          <AnalitycsS />
          <p className="ml-3">Analitycs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="overflow-auto">{pantalla}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know how to make the button click on it and change the screen to become active, the class is shadow-active

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to put my functions close to design, so I create a class with Javascript functions and export one by one. Once you do that you can import them into your component without creating directly in the class.